# To read dynamic column changes from source table

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I am using `Talend` free version
I have below requirement:

My source is `MS ACCESS`; table `SRC_CUST`.

**SRC_CUST**

```
CUST_ID     CUST_NAME
  101          ABC  
  102          LMN
```

My target is `.csv` file `TGT_CUST`

Requirement: I am using `tAccessInput` component for `MS Access` table and I want to load that table into `.csv` file. My columns are varying day to day on daily basis.

Day 1: `SRC_CUST` has 2 columns `CUST_ID` and `CUST_NAME` so I need to load as it is into `.csv` file

Day 2: `SRC_CUST` has 3 columns `CUST_ID`, `CUST_NAME`, `CUST_ADD` so on day 2 I need to load these 3 columns without changing any code, means, I need to achieve column change dynamically .

**Note:** I am using `Talend` free version so I neither use any dynamic component nor dynamic data type. I cannot even add columns in "Edit schema" under basic settings of `tAccessInput` component because my columns are varying.

Please help me for same.

Thanks,
Vaishali Shinde

Comment: For MSSql there is a component called tDBColumnList that can be used to get the column names of a table. You can then iterate over the columns to dynamically build your query statement and then proceed with running it within the querying component. I don't know if you can use or another component exists for Access. Thought this could help.

Comment: There's a JDBC to MSAccess files, but without the dynamic schema it's really tough...
Thinking out of the box, you can still write the Java code manually and use the iCanAccess driver to push the result to csv. Or pay for the enterprise version.